# How to reset Spyder IDE (Python 2.7) graphic user interface?

Tags: python, user-interface, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to reset the interface I have tried to misaligned. 
[image: Misaligned Spyder interface]

I couldn't find it in settings. I have also tried uninstalling and reinstalling it. No luck.

Can you help me to reset it?

Thanks.

Comment: By any chance do you have a view tab with the option reset window layout? If you do, try that.

Comment: Yes, in view tab you can click on it and keep arranging one by one. But I want the default way.
Here I found a way, but its not working, the command line option isn't working in my case. 
https://pythonhosted.org/spyder/options.html?highlight=command%20line

Comment: @OkayLolz Did you solve the problem ? There's no answer you picked as a right one!

Answer (score 23):

(Spyder-dev here)

We will include a way to reset spyder configuration from within the user interface in the upcoming version (3.0.0).

---

In the meantime you can reset by opening a terminal window (cmd in windows.. shell in Mac/Linux) and typing

`spyder --reset`

If that still does not work you can erase the folder `.spyder` in your user folder

Windows
`X:\Users\username\.spyder2\` (or `X:\Users\username\.spyder\`)

Linux
`\home\username\.spyder2\` (or `\home\username\.spyder\`)

Comment: I don't think spyder --reset works on mac as it shows spyderlib not found error.

Comment: @OkayLolz, it doesn't work if you installed Spyder using its dmg installer. But as goanpeca mentioned, this will be solved in the upcoming Spyder release.

Comment: thanks a ton. `spyder  --reset` worked for me in ubuntu :)

Answer (score 17):

I'm using **Spyder 3.1.2**

Just go to <kbd>View</kbd> → <kbd>Window Layouts</kbd> → <kbd>Reset to Spyder default</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: doesn't reset to the actual default for me

Answer (score 2):

For anyone, who has problem restoring the defaults settings, 
Open Terminal and type:

```
rm -r ~/.spyder
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Spyder 2.3.9.
I was able to reset the windows using View->Reset Window Layout.

The original post could be on older version, where this option did not exist!

Comment: Normally this works for me.  But I detached the Console window and I can't put it back on (w/o restarting Spyder).  I thought I could drag it back over an area, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Tools >> Reset Spyder to Factory Defaults. Tested on Spyder 3.1.4

Answer (score 0):

I found a way arround this problem( works for me )
I had the issue that there were 2 seperated windows(I tried to reset the view but it didnt work)  and I couldn´t move one of them. 
My way arround it was to drag the non movable window a bit bigger(I tried to change its size) then that window became movable for me and I could drag it into the other to get the default view again.
Maybe it works for somebody aswell, just wanted to share.
(3.2.4)

Answer (score 0):

You only need update your Spyder version using this command on Anaconda Prompt

```
pip install -U spyder
```

It's has fixed on my IDE.

If you can't fix delete your Spyder folder (.spyder-py3) in your directory like : C:\Users*Your-User*

Answer (score 0):

Do following steps
View->Reset Window Layout.
*Also do not forget to restart the application.* It was not worked for me without restart.
I hope it should work for you.

If still this not work you can do Tools->Reset Spyder for factory default.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Anaconda Navigator and Spyder 3.3.2. Open Anaconda Prompt, then type:

```
spyder --reset
```

To open Anaconda Prompt in Windows: Click Start, search or select Anaconda Prompt from the menu.