# Anaconda Spyder can't show the program window on windows 8

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

My system is windows 8, and I download Anaconda python 3.4 from the official website. The spyder has been all well until yesterday, I can open the spyder, and the icon shows on my taskbar, but no matter how I click the icon, the program window doesn't show up on the screen. I have uninstalled and reinstalled the Anaconda, but still can't fix it. Any suggestion?

By the way, I usually open spyder from "Anaconda/Scripts/spyder.exe", is that a problem?

Answer (score 12):

I ran into the same problem after installing Spyder for Python 2.7 with an existing installation of Spyder running on Python 3.5.  What worked for me was the following: I closed all running Spyder applications, ran the "Reset Spyder Settings" shortcut for Anaconda2, and voila, spyder2 started displaying properly after running.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034114/how-to-reset-spyder-ide-python-2-7-graphic-user-interface "spyder --reset" in the command line worked for me

Answer (score 10):

`spyder --reset` from the command line works.

Answer (score 2):

For newbies like me, you got to use Anaconda prompt (windows cmd terminal didn't work for me) took a few mins to figure out to use Anaconda prompt to run spyder --reset command.