# How to reset Spyder IDE GUI back to normal zoom?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, spyder

I work on laptop and connect it to monitors of different resolutions. Recently, I was working on a 32" monitor so spyder IDE enlarged all menus and tabs. Then after few days I connected to a 24" monitor and now spyder is unable to reset the GUI back to normal. Although text in editor is fine but all menus buttons are zoomed-in and scrambled as shown below

[image]

I have tried resetting the IDE using the methods mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30034114/how-to-reset-spyder-ide-python-2-7-graphic-user-interface) and on Anaconda's [documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/#spyder-errors-or-failure-to-launch-on-windows) but it did not help.

For example, reseting through the view menu as follow didnot help.

[image]

Using the command `spyder --reset` on anaconda prompt provided following output, but it didn't reset the GUI

```py
(rmit37) C:\>spyder --reset
*** Reset Spyder settings to defaults ***
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\onlinehelp
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\temp.py
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\template.py
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\history.py
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\history_internal.py
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\workingdir
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\langconfig
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\spyder.lock
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\config\spyder.ini
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\config\transient.ini
removing: C:\Users\e103851\.spyder-py3\plugins

(rmit37) C:\>
```

I have also tried removing the **C:\Users\e103851.spyder-py3** folder altogehter but of no use.

Now I am stuck with this crazy looking GUI. I have also tried removing spyder along with all its folders and reinstalling it but to my surprise it didn't solve the issue.

Is there any recent way to reset the spyder IDE back to normal zoom level?

Comment: because you problem happened after switching monitors and using a laptop I suspect it has nothing to do with spyder itself but with windows. can you go to your display settings and check the `scale and layout` size configurations?

Comment: I have the same problem and the Windows settings for the scale and layout are all greyed out. I also went into Advanced scaling settings and turned off the option to "let Windows to try to fix apps so they're not blurry" but it didn't work. I'll be watching this thread.

Comment: Weird but easy way to fix:
https://superuser.com/a/1452558/936955

Answer (score 1):

I think I ran into a similar issue as well.

In Spyder, I resolved it by going to Tools > Preferences > Application > interface tab and in the Screen Resolution section, switching from "Enable auto high DPI scaling" to "Normal".